# Find regular expression match in string after a given index in Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala

I want to find a match (if any) for a regular expression on a string, but only testing after a given index. For example:

```
val p = "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*".r
val t = "const pi = 3.141592"
val m = p.findFirstMatchIn(t, start=5) // not real syntax
```

That is, I want to ignore the first `n = 5` characters of the string. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: `p.findFirstMatchIn(t.drop(5))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala's `.r` syntax is a thin wrapper around the original `java.util.regex.{Pattern, Matcher}` API. The original API provides more control. Use [`Matcher.region`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#region(int,%20int)):

```
scala> val m = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*").matcher(t)
scala> m.region(5, t.size)
scala> m.find()
scala> m.group(0)
res6: String = pi
```