# Get the index of a regex match in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

How do you get the index of a regex match on a String in Scala?

```
val body = "This is a 'long string' with long string in it."
println(body.indexOf("long string")) // 11
println(body.indexOf("long string", 12)) // 37

// I'm looking for something like this:
"""\slong string""".r.findIndexIn(body) // Should give Some(36)
"""\slong string""".r.findIndexIn(body, 37) // Should give None
```

Is there some easy way of doing this without looping through the characters find matches for `s"^${myRegex}"`? Or would I need to resort to using Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Match` class contains the properties describing a particular regex match, including the position, at which it starts.

Something like `"foo".r.findFirstMatchIn(bar).map(_.start)` should do what you ask.

But if you are really just looking for a substring, then `bar.indexOf("foo")` will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 3):

Building on Dima's fine answer: You can get a list of all match indices with a single pass through the target string.

```
"""\slong string""".r.findAllMatchIn(body).map(_.start).toList  //List(28)
""".long string""" .r.findAllMatchIn(body).map(_.start).toList  //List(10, 28)
"""Xlong string""" .r.findAllMatchIn(body).map(_.start).toList  //List()
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Dima and jwvh were helpful in finding what I needed, notably the functions provided by the [`Match`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex$$Match.html) class. For the sake of completeness and for future readers, here are the solutions I used for getting the index of a result *from a given index*, i.e. a function that observes the following behaviour:

```
findIndexFromPosition(body, """\slong string""", 0) // Some(36)
findIndexFromPosition(body, """\slong string""", 37) // None
```

Firstly using Java's `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857601/find-regular-expression-match-in-string-after-a-given-index-in-scala):

```
def findIndexFromPosition(body: String, pattern: String, fromIndex: Int): Option[Int] = {
    val regex = Pattern.compile("\\slong string\\s").matcher(body)
    regex.find(fromIndex) match {
         case true => Some(regex.end)
         case false => None
    }
}
```

And, with the help of jwvh's answer, the more Scalamatic way:

```
"""\slong string""".r.findAllMatchIn(body).map(_.start).find(_ > fromIndex)
```